# Simple.OData.Client not returning results, no error

Tags: c#, odata, simple.odata.client

I'm trying to read data from an OData V2 service using the Simple.OData.Client library, but I am having zero success after hours of hair-pulling.

```
using Simple.OData.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo();
    }

    public static async Task Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This happened");
        var client = new ODataClient("https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/");
        var packages = await client.FindEntriesAsync("Packages?$filter=Title eq 'SDK'");
        Console.WriteLine("Found packages: " + packages.Count());

        foreach (var package in packages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(package["Title"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code yields only `This happened` in the console, nothing else is printed and no exceptions are thrown. For some reason even the second print statement doesn't work... but why?

I am completely lost as to why this doesn't work.

This is literally a copy of the code from the Getting Started guide: https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Getting-started-with-Simple.OData.Client

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Why are you not `await`ing `Foo`?

Comment: Oh ffs... I read somewhere that there's no need to await if there's no result :( Just tried and it works. I would expect it to finish before terminating the program!